# display linkedin details in my text fields using php

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

i have managed to connect with Linkedin APi, so i can get the users details using below code.

```
 $response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,email-address,phone-numbers)');
        if($response['success'] === TRUE) {
          $response['linkedin'] = new SimpleXMLElement($response['linkedin']);
```

after that i need to display the retrieved details into text fields like this.

```
<table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td><?php echo $response['linkedin']->id;   ?></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>first Name</td>
                        <td><?php  echo $response['linkedin']->first-name; ?></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><?php  echo $response['linkedin']->email-address; ?></td>
                    </tr>


          </table>
```

Id is displaying correctly, but other details are not showing.
can anyone help on this.
thanks in advance

This is the xml output

```
this is : Array ( [linkedin] => KmRPC6CWFV Dam Path0 http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_TLYPQpjA4IBXz8ZqfCOhQxS04wrNB8dq_TE2Qxj8FDXkegggdXONDimxH0Wm9QKwqbH486ySW47__SJO ****@yahoo.com mobile +947123452 [info] => Array ( [url] => https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,email-address,phone-numbers) [content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 205 [request_size] => 500 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 20 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.482 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0.374 [pretransfer_time] => 1.076 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 538 [speed_download] => 363 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 1.466 [redirect_time] => 0 ) [oauth] => Array ( [header] => Authorization: OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="a484c4f1360fce43994eac522452b3b1",oauth_timestamp="1375865879",oauth_consumer_key="dxmlx1mg2xoz",oauth_token="70b05d77-fa98-49eb-bada-4be9d8533f29",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="05UWwjC1jC7lZT%2BBa8nWk8Isiz8%3D" [string] => GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fv1%2Fpeople%2F~%3A%28id%2Cfirst-name%2Clast-name%2Cpicture-url%2Cemail-address%2Cphone-numbers%29&oauth_consumer_key%3Ddxmlx1mg2xoz%26oauth_nonce%3Da484c4f1360fce43994eac522452b3b1%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1375865879%26oauth_token%3D70b05d77-fa98-49eb-bada-4be9d8533f29%26oauth_version%3D1.0 ) [success] => 1 )
```

hope this is the one.thanks for your support

Comment: what does ```print_r($response['linkedin'])``` give you?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => KmRPC6CWFV
    [first-name] => Dam
    [last-name] => Patho
    [picture-url] => 
    [email-address] => xxxx@yahoo.com
    [phone-numbers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 1
                )

            [phone-number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [phone-type] => mobile
                    [phone-number] => +0123456
                )

        )

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use hypens like that in PHP.
Try this:

```
<?php  echo $response['linkedin']->{'first-name'}; ?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: No. its same.just displaying as zero.

Comment: I overlooked the obvious. It's the hyphens which are the issue.

Comment: Thanks @bottleboot.its works fine.but can you tell me how can i display the phone number?

Comment: np!, does this work for the phone number?
```<?php  echo $response['linkedin']->{'phone-numbers'}->[0]->{'phone-number'}->{'phone-number'}; ?>``` If not could you also post the xml output? It might be easier to work it out like that?

Comment: <?php echo $response['linkedin']->{'phone-numbers'}->[0]->{'phone-number'}->{'phone-number'‌​}; ?>i tried ur method and tried this <?php echo $response['linkedin']->{'phone-numbers'}; ?>.but both are not working.

Comment: could you post the xml?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => KmRPC6CWFV
    [first-name] => Dam
    [last-name] => Patho
    [picture-url] => 
    [email-address] => ****@yahoo.com
    [phone-numbers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [total] => 1
                )

            [phone-number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [phone-type] => mobile
                    [phone-number] => +94123456
                )

        )

) i think u mean this?

Comment: No i mean what's inside the ```$response['linkedin']``` var before it's turned into a ```new SimpleXMLElement($response['linkedin'])```

Comment: $response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,email-address,phone-numbers)');

Comment: Ah, It should be :
```<?php echo $response['linkedin']->{'phone-numbers'}->{'phone-number'}->{'phone-number'‌​}; ?>```

Comment: it returns an error.unexpected syntax error.it appears an error in brackets

Comment: can u plz tell me what should i provide to u?.i am totally clueless here.

Comment: the easiest thing would be ```print_r($response)``` I guess. Before you do this : ```new SimpleXMLElement($response['linkedin']);```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34973/discussion-between-dam-forums-and-bottleboot)

Comment: i'm in chat, it might go faster :)